# Relationship troubles with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need help creating the relationship in entity framework as everything I have tried gives me errors when trying to add the migration or if I get passed that then I try to update the database and get an error about indexes with the same name.

```
public class Profile
{
    public Profile()
    {
        Environments = new HashSet<Environment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string VersionCreated { get; set; }

    public string DiskLocation { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual Instance OriginalInstance { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Environment> Environments { get; set; } 
}


public class Instance
{
    public Instance()
    {
        TestResults = new HashSet<TestResult>();
        Environments = new HashSet<Environment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }

    public string UserFriendlyName { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile LastKnownProfile { get; set; }

    public virtual Computer Computer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestResult> TestResults { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Environment> Environments { get; set; } 
}
```

The problem with the above classes is that the OrginalInstance property on the Profile class and the LastKnownProfile in the Instance class are supposed to just be foreign keys to those specific tables and they probably won't be the same very often. They can also both possibly be null.

I have tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>().HasRequired(i => i.LastKnownProfile);
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasRequired(p => p.OriginalInstance);
```

This gave me an `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'EcuWeb.Data.Entities.Instance' and 'EcuWeb.Data.Entities.Profile'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.` error.

and with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>().HasRequired(i => i.LastKnownProfile).WithOptional();
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasRequired(p => p.OriginalInstance).WithOptional();
```

The database adds a foreign key reference back to itself.

Comment: It seems you want to have one to one relationship between these two entities, try to use only one of the mappings commands: modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>().HasRequired(i => i.LastKnownProfile).WithOptional(p => p.OriginalInstance );

Comment: That is closer, but that is not what I am looking for the two properties do not relate to each other at all. They can and probably will be different almost every time. They should just be foreign keys to the respective table without relating to the others property eg. LastKnownProfile should contain a ProfileId and OriginalInstance  should contain a different InstanceId not the same one as what contains LAstKnownProfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...that the OrginalInstance property on the Profile class and the
>   LastKnownProfile in the Instance class are supposed to just be foreign
>   keys to those specific tables and they probably won't be the same very
>   often. They can also both possibly be null.

In this case you actually want *two one-to-many relationships* between `Profile` and `Instance` if I don't misunderstand your quote above. It would mean that many Profiles can have the same `OriginalInstance` and that many Instances can have the same `LastKnownProfile`. The correct mapping would look like this then:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.OriginalInstance)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("OriginalInstanceId"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>()
    .HasOptional(i => i.LastKnownProfile)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("LastKnownProfileId"));
```

The lines with `MapKey` are optional. Without them EF will create a foreign key with a default name.

Also note that you must use `HasOptional` (instead of `HasRequired`) if "both can possibly be null".